# Kmplayer thumbnail preview not working

Tags: kmplayer

My KmPlayer doesn't show thumbnail preview when I hover mouse to seek bar. In previous version of KMPlayer it was working fine. In the current(Latest) version this feature was disabled by default so I enable it in

> Preferences > General > OSD Messages > (tick) Show Thumbnail preview when seeking with mouse

[image]

Still it's not working also restarted after changing settings

**UPDATE**

It worked after restarting computer

Comment: Thanks for this, i just apply settings and re-open kmplayer then its worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

all you need is go to option tweak section check "show preview in the search" apply and ok restart Km player X64 you can see seek bar display next time when play movie